# Extjs multicolumn chart

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I want to create extjs 4 column chart with many columns for each 'x value'. I define 2 columns in 'series':

```
series: [
    {
        type: 'column',
        axis: 'left',
        xField: 'key',
        yField: ['val1']
    },
    {
        type: 'column',
        axis: 'left',
        xField: 'key',
        yField: ['val2'],
    }
]
```

It create second column on first column (p1 in [screenshot](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/2536/20111016-bs6v-6kb)), but i want to see second column near first (p2 in [screenshot](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/2536/20111016-bs6v-6kb)). What parameter i should add to get excepted chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
series: [{
    type: 'column',
    xField: 'key',
    yField: ['val1','val2']                                                         
}]
```

When you provide two or more values to the same series, you get what you are expecting. This type is called grouped bar/column series.